# How to access one component state in another component if those two component define in separate files in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to access state set in one component which is define in one file lets say one.js,to be access in other component file name Two.js.How to access state of one component in other component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you call/import one.js inside two.js?
if you do, you can pass the state from one.js using props.

EDIT:

To access the state from a page into another one, you'll have to use props. In tthis case, to access the state from one.js into two.js, that's what you could do:

Let's supose that PageOne is a class inside one.js, where you would import two.js:

```
import PageTwo from 'Two';
...
export default class PageOne extends React.Component{
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { somethingSomething: 'whatever'};
 }
  render() {
   return (
     <View>
       <PageTwo propsname = {this.state.somethingSomething}>
       </PageTwo>
     </View>
   )
  }
}
```

In the code above, you're passing the state for PageTwo(two.js), and now to show it:

```
…
export default class PageTwo extends React.Component{
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {alert(this.props.propsname)}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: No I dont call or import..Even if i did how i can access it using props.I mean i think props can be used to pass the value from parent to child in the same view or component,right?? can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: In react-native, as long as i know, you can't access the state from a page in another one as you were asking, what you can do is use props.  If the one.js and two.js are not parent and child related, you'll have to create a third page that will connect them as sisters, and then you'll be able to manipulate them by props.

Comment: Can give show me sample code on how to do that?? its really important please help..

Comment: Ok..thanks for code snipet..but tell me is it possible to access the state without importing or mentioning the component name as u did in PageOne by giving a PageTwo tag and passing a value via props..is there any other means to achieve the same thing????

Comment: So far, I have only been able to do this using props. But if I learn another method, I'll tell you.

Comment: How to do that from PageTwo to PageOne?

Comment: @Lucky_girl, its the same idea. You define the props on PageTwo and call them on PageOne.